# Why Would Javascript Programming Work on One Server but Not Another

Tags: javascript

Someone else created a Javascript multipage form that works fine on a Host Gator server.

However, on the client's own Windows IIS server with an HTTPS path, it no longer works. It is not loading the Javascript.

Can anyone shed light on this?  Is it an issue with Javascript version?  Could it be a path issue or a case issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open your JavaScript console (F12, *console* tab), you'll see that `Validator is not defined` and is causing an error.

Above it, you'll also see that your JavaScript files are getting blocked for being served over `http://` protocol instead of `https://` (causing the scripts to not execute).

To solve that, you might need to host the files on your own server, or to use alternative CDNs (you can just add `https` to the jQuery URL, but it won't work for `gen_validatorv4.js`).

Comment: It is in the <head> section for the header.php file.  Should it be on all the other pages as well?

Comment: @user2939031 Yes, in the `<head>` section, but apparently, it is causing an error because it is not served over `https://` Try actually hosting it on your domain (same thing for jQuery and Google Webfonts, they're getting blocked). You need to include it wherever it is used. If you don't know where it is used, visit multiple pages with your console open, and you'll see if there is an error or not.

Comment: Thank you for answering Blex.  I will follow your advice.  Thanks for helping a newbie.

Comment: @user2939031 No problem, please report back when you tried that. Also, I changed my answer, you might want to look at it.

Comment: It worked!!  I have wasted HOURS trying to figure this out and you solved it in a minute.  Do you have a PayPal account - would love to donate!

Comment: @user2939031 Haha, glad it worked out for you. That's kind of you, but I'm not looking for money, just trying to figure out problems as a hobby. If this answer solved your problem, you can mark it as "Correct answer", that will be enough of a reward :)

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by placing the Jquery and Javascript files on the client server and referencing them with an absolute HTTPS path in the header.php file.